# MSMQ communication between different servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, msmq

I'm running into a permissions issue that I think is related to domain permissions/active directory but I'm a developer and not a systems person.

I have an MSMQ queue configured on a Windows 2003 server.  It is part of the ACME domain.

I have three other servers with an application that communicate with it.  Two are Windows 2003 machines and one is a Windows 2008 server machine running active directory all of which are NOT part of the ACME domain, the domain shows up as TEST.local.
The two Windows 2003 machines work fine being able to READ the queue defined.

My application running under the Win2k8 machine I get the error: 'System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Access to Message Queuing system is denied.'

I have the MSMQ queue configured to basically allow for Everyone and ANONYMOUS with full access.  Is there anything I can do to get this resolved?  Unforunately I am stuck with the Windows 2003 servers for the forseeable future, nor can I revert the Win2k8 machines back.

thanks!

edit: updated which domain machines reside.

Comment: Is there a trust between the two Windows domains?

Comment: dont believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean different forests? Different domains within the same forest shouldn't have problems.

You don't say what operation you are trying to perform. As you have opened up queue permissions then it won't be a send(). I expect therefore that you are trying to read from the queue which uses the RPC protocol and has a different bunch of security obstacles.

[Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

[Cross-forest MSMQ? You need to be trusting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx)

["How do I send MSMQ messages between domains?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/14/how-do-i-send-msmq-messages-between-domains.aspx)

[MSMQ 3.0 too secure for you?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/01/15/msmq-3-0-too-secure-for-you.aspx)

Comment: I am trying to read from the MSMQ on the machine in the ACME domain.  I'm working thru the ISP trying to get this resolved, they installed a bunch of new servers at our request but so far its been a nightmare.

Comment: If the Windows 2003 servers can access the queue hosted in the ACME domain then you should be able to get the Windows 2008 server to read the queue too. The basic operation is going to be the same between the different operating systems. Work through the RPC-specific blog posts and you should be OK.